# Regex extract words

Tags: regex, vba

I find the regex world a bit big at the moment and struggle to get going with my "capture". Could you help me on my way here? I'm building a sort of search engine and need to organize the input string.

Given VBA as the tool, and RegEx probably the best way, consider the following string:

`input = "header ++add this ++and;a --k101 --k102"`

Where "space" should be infront of "++" or "--" but the user should be able to search for "split word"

At the end I want to be left with 2 arrays:
`addArr = ["header", "add this", "and;a"]`
`remArr = ["k101","k102"]`

My line of thought so far is to first check for "++" then for "--" and add them as I go

```
if instr(input,"++")>0 then 
    tmpArr =split(input,"++")
    for i = 1 to ubound(tmpArr) '0 is before the split, 1 is after the split 
       '''Do some regex here'''
    next i
end if
```

I might be overlooking a more clever way to achieve the end result, but I might add that the input can vary from:
`input = hey ++add this ++and;a` (no "--"'s)
`input = hey --remThis ++add this --remAlsoThis` 
and even just
`input = hey`

So I have to run a test to check if regex is needed, and if it is I thought I should run

```
Dim RE As Object, ptrn As String
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
ptrn = "(?)(\+\+)" 'obviously wrong, but "working pattern"
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = ptrn
End With
output = RE.Replace(input, "$2")
```

And fill my arrays that way. But I'm struggling to get the right pattern down.
Could you help me on my way with a pattern, or lead me on a better path to my goal?

If it makes the solution any different, I don't know, but I'm aiming for a 2 dimensional array, where the second dimension describes if the word/sentence IS or IS NOT ended with an ";a" (true or 1) which is needed later in my code...

Comment: You probably can simply split with whitespace, and then loop over all the items, and if one starts with `+++` add its substring to the `addArr`, if it does not start with `---`, at the whole item to `addArr`, and if it starts with `---` add the substring to `remArr`.

Comment: I'm guessing you're right. I was blinded by the thought of regex coming to the rescue. I'll go down the split by whitespace-path and see if I come out at the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex was not the way to go. Solved it by splitting on whitespaces and multiple operations on each element in the resulting array.